# Convert Swift Dictionary to String

Tags: swift, ios8

For testing and debugging I am trying to put the content of Dictionary to a String. But have no clue hows it going to achieve. Is it possible? If yes, how.

Dictionary is fetched from web service so I have no idea the key values it have. I want to use the data in app.

In Objective C %@ was enough to store anything in NSString.

Comment: %@ on an object, just calls the description method. So you can just do myDict.description to get a String.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Just use the `description` property of `CustomStringConvertible` as

[image: Example:]

Note: Prior to Swift 3 (or perhaps before), `CustomStringConvertible` was known as `Printable`.

Comment: thats exactly I was looking for. println cannot be assigned to object - String in my case. (Y)

Comment: is it possible to then convert it back to dictionary?  use case is storing on server in string field.

Answer (score 41):

Dictionary to string with custom format:

```
let dic = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]

let cookieHeader = (dic.flatMap({ (key, value) -> String in
    return "\(key)=\(value)"
}) as Array).joined(separator: ";")

print(cookieHeader) // key2=value2;key1=value1
```

Comment: will it work if the value in dictionary is not string:string and is string:array.

Comment: "\(key)=\(value)" is calling description on your behalf so the result would be for instance `key=["1", "2", "3"]`. If you want something different you have to customize yourself.

Comment: talking about usage of flatMap

Comment: The element returned from flatMap is a string, disregarding what the key and value are, so yes, it will work with string:array.

Comment: @Jano Thanks a lot +1 , Worked like charm!!

Comment: Very nice @Jano. It also explores the concept of flatMap.

Answer (score 13):

[Jano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786978/4691224) using **Swift 5.1**:

```
let dic = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
let cookieHeader = dic.map { $0.0 + "=" + $0.1 }.joined(separator: ";")
print(cookieHeader) // key2=value2;key1=value1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just print a dictionary directly without embedding it into a string:

```
let dict = ["foo": "bar", "answer": "42"]

println(dict)
// [foo: bar, answer: 42]
```

Or you can embed it in a string like this:

```
let dict = ["foo": "bar", "answer": "42"]

println("dict has \(dict.count) items: \(dict)")
  // dict has 2 items: [foo: bar, answer: 42]
```