# Convert dictionary data into HTTP url format

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to send dictionary data using POST method dataTaskWithRequest() can send this only in string URL format.

How can we convert dictionary data into HTTP URL format?

Here is an example:

```
let parameters = [
    "first": "name",
    "second": ["a", "b"],
    "third": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
]
```

convert it into

```
first=name&second[]=a&second[]=b&third[x]=1&third[y]=2&third[z]=3
```

using swift 2.3

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dictionary to json using this code and set HTTPBody

```
    let jsondata = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    request.HTTPBody = jsondata
```

Comment: you are right but HTTPBody data is not coming in POST variable on php server. it is coming as json file. i need to send it on POST variable.

Comment: You can parse json in php server `$string = file_get_contents("/home/michael/test.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Converted the `Dictionary` using below code :

```
let postString = (dictionaryParameters.flatMap({ (key, value) -> String in
            return "\(key)=\(value)"
        }) as Array).joined(separator: "&")
```

and attached the string in `httpBody` of the request :

```
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

got the response finally.

Got help from this link:

- [Convert Swift Dictionary to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372198/convert-swift-dictionary-to-string)